# QGIS Legend from WMS

Tags: qgis, wms, legend

I use QGIS 3.4.5 and want to create a map from a WMS. The problem is the legend, which is created automatically from the WMS. The quality is very bad and the writing is barely legible. 
How can I change the formatting of this WMS legend?
I know how to change the size of the legend, but the quality of the writing is pretty bad, even if I increase the size of the legend

WMS Example:
https://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dnrw250

[image]

Comment: Since it is the basemap, is the legend really necessary? The contents you lay above the basemap tend to be the interesting ones.

Comment: I use this WMS only as an example, because it is a free accessible WMS. The problem  occurs with other WMS, too.

Comment: That I am aware of, but how many WMS have a legend as complex as this one?

Comment: In my company we have a lot of these services with complex legends.

Comment: If these layers are used frequently, you could manually re-create their legend once and save it as a template.

Comment: Is there any other possibility to change the quality of the legend?Rebuild of the legend is a plan, but to time consuming.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.